# How to make a ListView scroll only to the right?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview

I am creating a program for restaurants. And this program is controlled through a touch monitor. This program has a listview and if you scroll through it for a long time, a screen starts to appear (see here https://yadi.sk/d/rqe6_T82RFN2VQ). But if i remove the scrollview, then it starts working normally. I would like to ask how to make it so that you can only scroll to the right. Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: It is unclear what is the problem from your description, also you video is too long, please tell at which second your problem happens

Answer (score 0):

Are the upper and lower fields in the same frame?

You can use `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`

to enable only scrolling left and right and cancel scrolling up and down in a scrollViewer.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't clarify the question. I need that the listview can only be scrolled to the right, and scrolling to the left should be prohibited

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by capturing the ScrollChanged event and using `ScrollToHorizontalOffset` to undo the left scroll:

**In XAML**

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ListView_ScrollChanged">
    <!-- (rest of ListView code) -->
</ListView>
```

**In code-behind**

```
private void ListView_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Decorator border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sender as ListView, 0) as Decorator;
    ScrollViewer sv = border.Child as ScrollViewer;

    if (e.HorizontalChange <= 0)
        sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(sv.HorizontalOffset - e.HorizontalChange);
}
```